# Problem hitting REST endpoint in Spring Boot 2.2.0 application

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I try to create a Spring Boot REST application with GraphQL and MongoeDB (I start from that article https://medium.com/oril/spring-boot-graphql-mongodb-8733002b728a). The application start but I got 404 error when I try to post something to a endpoint.

I read also that `@PostConstruct` is not supported anymore with 2.2.0 (it's another problem I'll try to figure out later, I try to preload the database during startup).

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tsoai-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.10</lombok.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.5</commons-io.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My main application file look like this (nothing very special!):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

MainController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/query")
public class MainController {

    private GraphQL graphQL;
    private GraphQlUtility graphQlUtility;

    @Autowired
    MainController(GraphQlUtility graphQlUtility) throws IOException {
        this.graphQlUtility = graphQlUtility;
        graphQL = graphQlUtility.createGraphQlObject();
    }

    @PostMapping(path= "/")
    public ResponseEntity query(@RequestBody String query){
        ExecutionResult result = graphQL.execute(query);
        System.out.println("errors: "+result.getErrors());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result.getData());
    }

}
```

When I post on `http://localhost:8080/query`, I got this error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-10-19T16:10:19.136+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/query"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will match `/query/` only but not `/query` . If you want to match both `/query` and `/query/` , you can just leave `path` of the `@PostMapping` in the query method as the default.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/query")
public class MainController {

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity query(@RequestBody String query){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be a reason for this error that Spring boot is not scanning this class. Please try to add ComponentScan annotation on Spring boot main class with the package where you keep your controllers as given below.
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.example"})

Comment: Yeah I read about atComponentScan but I think you should use it only if you get rid of atSpringBootApplication annotation.

Comment: I think it's not like we use this annotation to get rid of SpringBooApplication annotation but to put additional configuration for component scanning. You can have multiple @ComponentScan annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Check the port on which your Spring Server is running, According to the medium post they have configured it to run on **:8000** while you're hitting on **:8080**.
The error states the same that it cannot find any controller mapped to this  api-endpoint.

http://localhost:8000/query/

`

Comment: I changed it for :8080 because I have already something on :8000 port.

Comment: add a '/' after query.